# Finalize on http interceptor not being hit when token expires

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack, mean

I'm trying my hand at MEAN for the first time and I'm coming up against some resistance with error handling on jwt token expiration. I've got the error handler here on the express server.

```
const handleUnauthorisedError = (err: any, req: any, res: express.Response, next: any) => {
    if (err.name === "UnauthorizedError") {
        if (err.message === "jwt expired") {
            res.header("Token-Expired", "true");
        }

        console.error(err);
        res.status(401);
        return res.json({ message: `${err.name}: ${err.message}` }).end();
    }
};
```

Which is then being added here after the routes.

```
app.use("/api", setupRoutes());
app.use(handleUnauthorisedError);
```

Within my angular interceptor I've got this error handler

```
private handle401Error = (err: HttpErrorResponse, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => {
    console.log(err.headers);

    if (err.headers.has("Token-Expired")) {
        this.tokenSubject.next(null);

        return this.authenticationService.refresh().pipe(switchMap(() => {
            return next.handle(this.addToken(req));
        }), catchError(() => {
            return this.authenticationService.logoutExpired().pipe(finalize(() => {
                this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
            }));
        }));
    }

    return this.authenticationService.logoutExpired().pipe(finalize(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    }));
}
```

However finalize never seems to occur, unless I terminate the express server. It's as if the connection is persisting maybe?

Z

Answer (score 0):

I think `finalize` does not occur because this operator works when the source **completes or throws an error**. More on this [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html).

Think of the `finalize` operator as the `finally` statement from `try/catch`.

In your code, you are only emitting values.

Another question that arises is **why** would you use `finalize`? 
I'd use this when I'm dealing with http calls.

But, if for some reason you still want to use this operator, you could make sure that you throw an error from `this.authenticationService.logoutExpired()`:

```js
 logoutExpired () {
  // Some logic here..
  return throwError('err');
}
```

[Here is a little StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hc5bbp?file=index.ts).

Comment: So is the response from the express api not completing? I've used that same interceptor code on an app connected to an dot net core api and it worked fine.

Comment: It might be something wrong with express, I didn’t pay much attention to it. If you remove some error handling.code you should see whether the BE api is working or not. Try to put some console logs here and there to check the flow of your app. Let me know if it worked!